# Vim cannot rebind Home/End keys

Tags: vim

I'd like `<Home>` to perform `g<Home>` and have tried

```
map <Home> g<Home>
noremap <Home> g<Home>
map <Home> g^
noremap <Home> g^
map <home> g<home>
noremap <home> g<home>
map <home> g^
noremap <home> g^
```

Nothing seems to work, the behavior stays the same. At any point I am able to type <kbd>g</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to do the right thing (go to home/end of soft line in wrapped file)

typing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> yields `^[[1~` (and End yields `^[[4~`).

Comment: Isn't `g+Home` the same as `^`?

Comment: `nnoremap <Home> g<Home>` worked here.

Comment: @ExplosionPills No. g<Home> goes to the first column of the current **screen** line. ^ goes to the first **non-blank** column of the current line.

Comment: g^ is actually what I want, thanks for pointing out the distinction @DanHulme

Answer (score 0):

I bound it like this:

`noremap <ESC>[1~ g^`

Comment: It can be bound to a special key to prevent this from causing the `<ESC>` key being waited on for a second.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer to a similar question, [Can't map Home button in vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16961256/717124), maybe it helps.

In special:

From `:h xterm-end-home-keys`:

```
  On some systems (at least on FreeBSD with XFree86 3.1.2) the codes that the
  <End> and <Home> keys send contain a <Nul> character.  To make these keys send
  the proper key code, add these lines to your ~/.Xdefaults file:

  *VT100.Translations:      #override \n\
        <Key>Home: string("0x1b") string("[7~") \n\
        <Key>End: string("0x1b") string("[8~")
```

If that doesn't work, you could try `:set t_kh=^V^[[1~`. If it work you can enclose it on a check of your terminal type. 
Additional information can be found at `:h terminal options`